# How to share/duplicate column information in 2 or more lists

Tags: sharepoint, list

I have a 'master' list with say, 10 columns (1 - 10). I have another list(2) and want to display what is in, say column 3 in list 1 in list(2) so that both lists show the same info.
I also want the ability to change content in column (3) from either list 1 or list 2 so that both are updated.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  You'll have to write an event receiver.